# Restore Percona Xtrabackup to new database

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm afraid that this question may be a duplicate, but I cannot find it being asked anywhere else. If it is a duplicate, please direct me to the thread where it is answered.

We are using the Percona Xtrabackup (innobackupex) to back up our very large database. We need to import this backup into a new database on the same server (We are backing up DB A on Server 1 and want to import it back into DB B on Server 1). How do we do this? I tried creating DB B and copying the data files into the directory but it didn't seem to work.

I'm not that familiar with InnoDB and don't want to risk taking our live database down by making a mistake on this (I've had issues with crashing InnoDB engine before and not being able to get it back up)

We are calling innobackupex in probably the simplest method possible:

```
innobackupex --no-timestamp /root/tmp/databases/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to copy all the data from one schema into another schema using XtraBackup there is a blog post on the MySQL Performance Blog that describes how you can do it titled [Migrating between MySQL schemas with Percona Xtrabackup](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/06/10/migrating-between-mysql-schemas-with-percona-xtrabackup/).

This is one of the few cases not documented in the manual.

Comment: I guess that would be good information to have. We are not doing any backup preparation or compression, encryption, or anything else. OP updated to show our invocation line.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time in the manual (Just to figure out how the system worked in the first place) but haven't seen anything talking about how to do a restore to a live server on the same machine that the backups were taken on.

Comment: The manual I'm looking at (2.0.6) has a detailed tutorial named 'How to setup a slave for replication in 6 simple steps with Xtrabackup.'  That should work for you.  Without any compression/encryption options, I suspect you can likely just rsync the data to a new directory.  I'd test it for you but I'm still waiting for my backup hardware to arrive.

Comment: I see that section, as well, but we don't have extra hardware and we don't want to set up replication. Our backups and live database are on the same server and we want to copy that live database into a second, development database.

Comment: It would be the same except stop where you start setting up replication...

Comment: If I'm misunderstanding and you're not trying to set up a second instance of mysql server with the same data as the first, but instead trying to copy the data from one schema to another within the same mysql server instance, then you can use [Migrating between MySQL schemas with Percona Xtrabackup](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/06/10/migrating-between-mysql-schemas-with-percona-xtrabackup/).  You're going to be in a world of hurt if you mix development and production databases on the same server if/when dev runs into issues.  I wouldn't do that if there was **any** other option.

Comment: This is an edge case and that is exactly what we need to do. We are not doing development on this machine, but need a publicly available copy of a trash version of our live DB. Make sense? Your link looks to be exactly what we need to do. Can you update your answer with this information so that I can accept it?

Thanks for your help!